# Microsoft Access UI design

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am having trouble breaking these boxes apart so far when I enter 1 value it enters that value in all boxes. I need to be able to enter multiple different values for each different field. Users are searching a table for ID OD and Width and need to search for multiple items entering different ID OD and widths in one form.

[my microsoft access UI form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrWV6.png)

Answer (score 1):

If these are search text boxes, you must make them all **unbound**. Then you'll have to supply a fixed number of controls.

Or bind them to a "search" table, and have only one row of controls in the Detail section. Then the user can create as many "search" records as they like.

Comment: Thank you, these are text boxes, but I dont understand what you mean by supply a fixed number of controls? or how to create a search table how would I make each search created go into a table that can then be added to until all the materials needed are found and put into that table